# I want to read commands from a text file

Tags: c++, string, list, file, fstream

I want to read commands for my adjacency list graph to follow.

```
5
ADD 0 1
ADD 1 2
ADD 2 3
ADD 3 1
ADD 2 0
LIST 2
DFS 2
BFS 2
REMOVE 1
```

I can't understand how to read this from file and call respective functions as addEdge(0,1) for ADD 0 1 and for all others.

I tried using `getline()` but I can't understand how to get the numbers from the string.

Isn't there any way to read from a file like if the file only had ADD commands we could use `while(file >> str >> num1 >> num2)`

Comment: Use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse the lines further.

Comment: I can't use sstream.

Comment: _"I can't use sstream."_ Why??

Comment: Can you please elaborate on not being able to use the `<sstream>` header (I assume)? Is it a school exercise or similar, where you're given artificial limitations? What other limitations are there?

Comment: I can use <cstdlib>.

Comment: If you can't use `std::istringstream` then read the first "command", then depending on the "command" you read its arguments and then perform the operation (or store it for later "execution"). You have to be careful though, because if there's an error in the input things might go haywire quickly, and it's probably not even possibly to try and continue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As usual, no C++ library headers, C functions only, no convenient `std::vector`, `std::string` etc. Oh, my favourite "C++" classes.

Comment: @GillBates Yes, they leave us a lot of _degenerated and confused human material_ in the industry. We should sue those profs to pay back all of these working hours to bang these poor minds back in shape.

Comment: C++ in name only. Likely users of C+++ will have the same problem with C++ and the cycle of stupid will continue.

Comment: You performed no research. This is asked almost daily, meaning there are **MILLIONS** of existing questions on the subject. This next part isn't your fault, but: I have entirely run out of patience for such occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't there any way to read from a file like if the file only had ADD commands we could use
>
> ```
> while(file >> str >> num1 >> num2)
> ```

You can use some code like

```
 std::string command;
 while(file >> command) {
     if(command == "ADD") {
         int num1, num2;
         if(!(file >> num1 >> num2) {
             std::err << "Unexpected input error" << std::endl;
         }
         else {
             addEdge(num1,num2);
         }
     else if(command == "LIST")
         int num1;
         if(!(file >> num1) {
             std::err << "Unexpected input error" << std::endl;
         }
         else {
             list(num1);
         }
     }
     else if(command == "DFS") {
        // etc.
     }
     // etc.
 }
```